# Is the order of the rows in the ResultSet constant for the same SQL query via JDBC on the same state of DB data?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

Trying to write a job that executes SQL query in Java using JDBC drivers (the DB vendors can be either Oracle, DB2 or Postgres).
The query does not really matter. Let’s say it filters on certain values in few columns in 1 DB table and the result is few thousand rows.

For each row in the ResultSet I need to do some logic and sometimes that can fail.

I have a cursor position so, I “remember” last successfully processed row position.

Now I want to implement a “Resume” functionality in case of failure in order not to process again the entire ResultSet.

I went to JDBC spec of Java 8 and found nothing about the order of the rows (is it the same for the same query on the same data or not)?
Also failed to find anything in DB vendors specs.

Anyone who could hint where to look for the answer about row order predictability?

Comment: The ResultSet has to return the rows in the order which the database has returned them. The **only** way to have a guaranteed order in a result is to use `ORDER BY` in your SQL query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you should make that an answer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, the ORDER BY is an option but even on a numeric column it could be quite pricy in terms of performance. That would be probably my last choice.

Comment: But an `order by` is the **ONLY** (really: the **only**) way that you can get a guaranteed order of the result. There is no alternative if you have to rely on the order of the result. This is how relational databases work. There is no such thing as a "default sort" order. You **have** to use an `ORDER BY` if you need a guaranteed sort order.

Answer (score 1):

You can guarantee the order of rows by including an `ORDER BY` clause that includes all of the columns required to uniquely identify a row. In fact, that's the *only* way to guarantee the order from repeated invocations of a SELECT statement, even if nothing has changed in the database. Without an unambiguous ORDER BY clause the database engine is free to return the rows in whatever order is most convenient for it at that particular moment.

Consider a simple example:

You are the only user of the database. The database engine has a row cache in memory that can hold the last 1000 rows retrieved. The database server has just been restarted, so the cache is empty. You `SELECT * FROM tablename` and the database engine retrieves 2000 rows, the last 1000 of which remain in the cache. Then you do `SELECT * FROM tablename` again. The database engine checks the cache and finds the 1000 rows from the previous query, so it immediately returns them because in doing so it won't have to hit the disk again. Then it proceeds to go find other 1000 rows. The net result is that the 1000 rows that were returned *last* for the initial SELECT are actually returned *first* for the subsequent SELECT.

Comment: Please see my comment under the question about ORDER BY overhead. The data set state does not change during the job run (as mentioned in the question

Comment: @aviad - I updated my answer to better explain why ORDER BY is necessary.